# Setf variable to computing time?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to set variable to computing time like this

```
(setf a (time (+ 1 1)))
```

but instead of time I get this

```
Break 1 [7]> a
2
```

How can I set a to computing time?

Comment: in your question the last line `How can I set a to computing time?` is not proper please make it proper

Comment: It seems to suggest that `a` is not defined. Did you define it?

Comment: It get defined but to wrong value.

Comment: It doesn't have the wrong value;  the [documentation for `time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_time.htm) says that the in `(time form)`, "time prints various timing data and other information to trace output" and that it returns "the values returned by the form."  The value of `(+ 1 1)` should surely be `2`.   The answers here show how can get the elapsed time as a value, or can get the output that's written to the trace output as values, depending on which you actually wanted (you didn't say, precisely, but I expect that by computing time you mean the former).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the answer of Lars.

`TIME` writes implementation dependent information to the trace output. If you want its output as a string:

```
(with-output-to-string (*trace-output*)
  (time (+ 1 1)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [GET-INTERNAL-RUN-TIME](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get__1.htm) (or [GET-INTERNAL-REAL-TIME](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get_in.htm)):

```
(setf a
      (let ((start (get-internal-run-time)))
        (+ 1 1) ;This is the computation you want to time.
        (- (get-internal-run-time) start)))
```

Divide by [INTERNAL-TIME-UNITS-PER-SECOND](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_intern.htm) if you want the result in seconds.

You would probably want to make a function or macro if you do this a lot.

Comment: It might be useful to make sure that the compiler has not removed the computation, because it creates no side-effects, can be computed at compile time and/or the result is not used.